# strcat() add extra characters at the beginning

Tags: c, concatenation

I would like to concatenate 2 strings in C using strcat(), but it is always add some random characters to the beginning of the new concatenated string.
Could someone please tell me why is this happening and how to solve it?

This is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void)
{
  
  char text[100];
  
  strcat(text, "Line 1");
  strcat(text, "Line 2");

  printf("%s", text);
  
  return 0;
}
```

When I execute this I get the following output:

```
???    Line1Line2
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I can not reproduce.

Comment: If `text` is a global variable as apparently shown, there should not be problem, because it is initialised to all 0 value. But if `text` is actually a local variable, it isn't initialised and using `strcat` on an uninitialised variable is *undefined behaviour*. Please post the exact, complete, code that you have, which should `#include` the necessary libraries.

Comment: Thank you it is the solution, I had to initialise text first.

Comment: Good, but the code shown isn't the code you are using. Another solution is to use `strcpy` instead of the first `strcat`.

Comment: Yes I have just fixed the code, people should allow some time before closing topics, it is honestly a bit annoying. It is solved anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ddabrahim: No, people should not allow time before closing topics. If the question is repaired to make it useful, it can be reopened, and closing it until such time avoids cluttering Stack Overflow with multiple answers guessing what the problem actually was. Where patience can be useful is in taking the time to compose a fully prepared statement of the question, including following the guideline to provide a [mre] when suitable. For this question, it would have taken only slight effort to provide a program that correctly reproduced the issue instead of one that did not.

Comment: I understand. I have fixed the problem. Could you reopen the topic now please? I don't want to do the same edit just to trigger reopening. I was notified I am going to be banned if I post one more question that does not follow the guidelines. I am honestly trying, I do my best to follow the guidelines but people act so fast. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the #include directives and verified the above code does reproduce my problem. I'm going to make sure in the future to always provide a working example.

Comment: @ddabrahim: When replying to other people's comments, beware that the person you are replying to will only be notified of your comment if you use the `@` syntax with their name, when replying to them. If you don't use this syntax, then the person you are replying to may not notice your comment. Press the "Help" button when writing a comment for further information. You will automatically be notified of all comments to your question, but other people will not automatically be notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
strcat(text, "Line 1");
```

has undefined behavior, because both arguments of the `strcat` function call must point to strings, i.e. to null-terminated sequences of characters. However, the first argument is not guaranteed to point to a string, because `text` consists of indeterminate values, because it is not initialized.

You have two options to fix this bug. You can either

- before the first call to `strcat`, set the first character of `text` to a terminating null character, i.e. `text[0] = '\0';`, so that `text` contains a valid (empty) string, or
- replace the first function call to `strcat` with [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), because `strcpy` does not require that the first function argument points to a valid string.